# AJAX Success Message for Updated Row

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table in which each row is a form:

```
<form class="update_record">
    <td><textarea name="feedback"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" class="update_record"><span class="update-success" style="display:none;"></span></td>
</form>
<form class="update_record">
    <td><textarea name="feedback"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" class="update_record"><span class="update-success" style="display:none;"></span></td>
</form>
```

form repeats...

ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.update_record').submit(function() {

var $form = $(this);
var serializedData = $form.serialize();

request = $.ajax({
    url: "...",
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData
});

//success
request.done(function (){
     $('.update-success').show();
});
```

I want to display a success message only on the row that was submitted. Current code shows success message for every row. How can I specify only the row that was updated?

Comment: How does the ajax call happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your submit handler looks something like:

```
$('.update_record').submit(function(){})
```

Within the handler `this` is the instance of the form event occurs on. Store a reference to it that you can pass into callback and then you can look for instance of the element you want using `find()`

```
$('.update_record').submit(function() {

  var $form = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: '...',
    /* other options*/
    success: function(response) {
      $form.find('.update-success').show();
    }

  });
});
```

If you are using  button click handler ... `this` is the button and the span would be found using `next()`

Comment: I tried replacing $('.update-success').show(); with $form.find('.update-success').show(); but it does not work (added code above). Am I missing something?

Comment: missing initial `$`  for `$('.update_record')` ...also is that code wrapped in `document.ready`?

Comment: Ooooo ...major bug...your html is invalid. Can't use form as child of `<tr>`. Browser will move form tag out of the table ...look at live html generated will have empty forms

Comment: Need to reinvent this without using forms . Use button click to trigger ajax. The `$btn=$(this)` and do `$btn.next().show()`. Or put tables inside forms